# SQLite Compact framework

Tags: sqlite, compact-framework, version, wrapper

I have both PC and Mobile application using SQLite. I have installed and used dll version 1.0.66 and when I have update my dlls to 1.0.85 from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and I can see PC program working with SQLite database very well but compact framework seems didn't like it.

I did add System.Data.SQLite and when I try to compile it I get

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I did remove and add System.Data reference but it didn't work. I removed System.Data.SQLite (1.0.85) and added reference again but chose 1.0.66 one then it worked.

I am really confused, why I cant use the latest verion of the reference/dll? Do I have to always have to use the old version on compact framework ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A public key token of `b77a5c561934e089` means that you're referencing a desktop assembly.  You must reference a Compact Framework assembly in a Compact Framework application.  Those downloads are near the bottom of the page you reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never thought that the compact framework assembly will be different.